# Discord.py disabling command in channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to disable the command in one channel, but the command is still working.

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.id != '923252963105976341':
        await ctx.send('Test')
    elif ctx.message.channel.id == '923252963105976341':
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `discord.py` the `channel.id` attribute is always `int` type.

```
>>> ctx.channel.id
852838885389762581 #Possible output
>>> ctx.channel.id
'852838885389762581' #Impossible output
```

---

In your case you only have to change you code to this:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.id != 923252963105976341:
        await ctx.send('Test')
```

You can remove the last two lines, since they're completely useless.
Notice than `not(id != x)  =>  id == x`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you pasted channel id as a `string` instead of an `int`. You might also want to use `return` instead of creating an `elif` statement. It might mess with your code if you create more advanced commands.

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if ctx.message.channel.id == 923252963105976341:
        return # it will stop executing your command
    await ctx.send('Test')
```

[Python `return`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/)

Comment: Nice answer, in particular considering that the OP probably doesn't know about `return` statement. I've added an explaination about the uselessy of the last two lines of code so that reading our two answers the OP will have an helping hand for his whole python and not only for discord.py. +1